# Cant parse array/json while stored via file

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have stored a file which contains my array. I make an ajax call to retrieve that information stored in a file and creates my end result from that.

Issue is that once done.. If i used `array[1]` it will return a letter of s or even a quote. Its not recognizing my output to be an array / json. Why is this?

Is there a way to fix this? If i can even do it PHP side? Or is there any suggestions as to what would be an efficient and effective way in completing my task?

PHP Code:

```
$GenreArray = file_get_contents('/srv/AvailableGenres');
$second = "hello dog";

$Result = [trim($second), $GenreArray];
$Result = json_encode($Result);
echo $Result;
//$GenreArray returns: {"00's":"Includes Amy Whinehouse, Westlife, The Killers...","50's":"Includes Elvis Presley, Bobby Darien, Frankie Vaughan..."}
```

JS Code:

```
var genrearray = [];
genrearray = data[1];
console.log(genrearray[1]); //Would return " or a letter
```

With the JS, i would expect to see "50's"

Comment: Looks like you're having problems with escaping single quotes.

Comment: Hmm, i deleted the single quotes there and still same issue.

Comment: If i do `console.log(genrearray[0]);` "{" is returned.

Comment: try `$GenreArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('/srv/AvailableGenres'), true);`

Comment: Problem is at PHP side.$GenreArray is not a array, it's a string, I guess. You can try using JSON.parse() in genrearray variable on JS code too.

Comment: I tried Nguyens way but comes back a Null value. I tried JSON.parse but i receive `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character`